# Why is my form template not getting displayed in Django project

Tags: python, html, django, django-models

So I am new to django and I am sure this is not a very good question. I am working on a project in which I have a form (for database entry) for user. It is supposed to show up after I click on a link i;e Add E-Shop, **yet when I click on it, I remain on the same page** (even though the url is changed)

The redirecting link is like this:

```
<li class="nav-item" >
    <a class="nav-link" style="color: #ffffff" href="{%url "main:add-shop"%}">Add E-Shop</a>
</li>
```

My views.py file is below:

```
def emarket(request):
    if not request.user.is_authenticated:
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/login/')
    emarket = Emarket.objects.all().exclude(verify = False)
    pos = Emarket.objects.values_list('latt', 'lonn')
    a = np.array(pos)
    lat1=[]
    long1=[]
    for i in range(len(a)):
        lat1.append(a[i][0])
        long1.append(a[i][1])
    return render(request, 'main/emarket.html', {"emarket": emarket ,'lat' : lat1 , 'lng':long1 })


class AddShop(CreateView):   #this is my adding shop model
    model = Emarket
    fields = ['name', 'owner', 'city_location', 'description', 'logo', 'latt', 'lonn']
    template_name = "main/shop_form.html"
```

And following is my urls configuration:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

app_name = 'main'

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^home/', views.index, name='index'),    # Home page
    url(r'e-market/', views.emarket, name = 'emarket'),     # rain water 
    url(r'e-market/add-eShop/$', views.AddShop.as_view(), name = 'add-shop'),   # Add an E shop
]
```

My form template is by the name 'shop_form.html'
shop_form.html :

```
 **<form method="post" novalidate enctype="multipart/form-data" class = "loginBox">
        {% csrf_token %}
            <h2 class = "register-text" style="font-size: 30px;"> Add E-Shop</h2>
            {{ form.as_p }}

        <input class = "register-button" type="submit" name="" value="Add Incubator">

    </form>**
```

Comment: You didn't define `template_name` in your `AddShop` view.

Comment: I made changes. Still does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to terminate the e-market URL:

```
 url(r'e-market/$', ...
```